# Oracle id contained in a view

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Is there a view in an oracle db which contains the Unix UID and GID for the 'oracle' account?

e.g. [oracle@xxxx ~]$ id
uid=650(oracle) gid=650(oinstall) groups=650(oinstall),651(dba)

when I do select uid from dual; it displays my own id and not that of the oracle account in Unix.

I want to know if this exists in any view or table - preferably a MGMT$ view for all databases in OEM - or if not in a v$ view instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue -

The following article talks about some of the information I required:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/doc.121/e25161/ecm.htm#EMPRF11499

```
select OWNER, TABLE_NAME from dba_tab_cols where column_name = 'OUI_HOME_GUID';
OWNER   TABLE_NAME
-----   ----------
SYSMAN  MGMT_LL_HOME_INFO
SYSMAN  MGMT$OH_HOME_INFO
SYSMAN  CM$MGMT_LL_HOME_INFO
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking in V$PROCESS.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_2101.htm

Not sure they're in there though.